# sqldatetime overflow sql server from android application using web service

Tags: android, web-services, sql-server-2008

I am calling a web service from my android application. When i call that service locally there is no problem , but if I am calling that service through my android application I am getting following error. The date time on ther server is just fine. Please help. I am using getdate() function in my stored procedure which i am using for insertion.

```
sqldatetime overflow. must be between 1/1/1753
```

Plz see the following web-service code, so that you will get better idea---

```
    [WebMethod]
    public String SaveHighRiskPrediction(int PatientCode, int PreganancyID, string txt_BP, string txt_BPdia, string txt_Weigth, string drp_ankle, 

string txt_Urinetest, string txt_albumin, string txt_symptoms, string drp_fhr)
    {
        try
        {
            //DateTime _today;
            //if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today), "dd-MM-yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out _today)) { }

            DateTime DateToday;
            string abc =System .DateTime .Now .ToString ("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            string [] def = abc.Split('-');
            string xyz  = def[2]+"/"+def[1]+"/"+def[0];
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateAll, "dd-MM-yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateToday)) { }
            Generic.db.Crital_Test_Insert(PatientCode,
                                          PreganancyID,
                                          txt_BP,
                                          txt_BPdia,
                                          txt_Weigth,
                                          drp_ankle,
                                          txt_Urinetest,
                                          "",
                                          txt_albumin,
                                          txt_symptoms,
                                          drp_fhr,
                                          "",
                                          "",
                                          "",
                                          "",
                                          "",
                                          "",
                                          "",
                                          Convert .ToDateTime (xyz),
                                          "",
                                            Convert .ToDateTime (xyz),
                                          "",
                                          "",
                                           Convert .ToDateTime (xyz),
                                            Convert .ToDateTime (xyz),
                                          "");
            return "Record Saved Successfully!";
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without posting your code, I can't tell you what is wrong "inline". However that error means you are trying to store an invalid date/time into the field, and very likely it is the non-null value representing some strange date such as 1/1/0 or a very very large date 1/1/9999.

To fix: you need to add debug to your server side code and handle invalid valid values in your data-access-layer - plus in the Android code you need to find and fix that bug.

Comment: Plz see the updated question for web-service code, you will get the better idea---